# How to use the same subselect in SELECT and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

for performance purpose, is it possible reuse in SELECT list a subselect from the WHERE clause, something like:

```
SELECT p.id, nItens FROM purchase AS p 
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM itens WHERE purchase_id=p.id) AS nItens) > 1
```

avoiding:

```
SELECT p.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM itens WHERE purchase_id=p.id) AS nItens 
FROM purchase AS p 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM itens WHERE purchase_id=p.id) > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use column aliases in the `having` clause, but not the `where` clause.  If you have a `having` clause without a `group by` -- in MySQL -- then it behaves like a `where`.  So you can do:

```
SELECT p.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM itens WHERE purchase_id=p.id) AS nItens 
FROM purchase AS p 
HAVING nItens  > 1;
```

However, your query is probably better written as:

```
select p.id, count(*) as nItens
from purchase p join
     itens i
     on p.id = i.purchase_id
group by p.id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Note that without the condition, you would need a `left outer join` for the same logic to keep purchases that have no matching iten.  Because your condition requires at least two such matches, you don't need the left join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM itens WHERE purchase_id=p.id) AS nItens 
FROM purchase AS p 
HAVING nItens  > 1
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it before asking, and got this error: Unknown column 'nItens' in 'where clause'

Comment: The one you tried before asking you put `AS nItens` in the where clause instead of the select

Comment: Not, that were to ilustrate the problem. Did you test your solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id
     , COUNT(n.purchase_id) ttl
  FROM purchase p 
  JOIN itens n 
    ON n.purchase_id = p.id
 GROUP
    BY p.id
HAVING ttl > 1
```